# Create Script for Count Ifs (2 Conditions)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently struggling with creating a [script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KZKdMp7-hqgCogyhoSOwYKcBgp_vJnVMNrOWmBME1TY/edit#gid=0) in Google Sheets.

**What would I like to do?**
I would like to calculate the workload of a team on different projects, i.e. how many hours have been spent per project, based on a capacity sheet in which all team members enter their different project work on a daily basis.

**Which solutions have I tried?** 
I tried the forms CountIF and SumIF, but I always get an error message: Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size.

The formula I tried out is: 
`=COUNTIFS('CAPACITY'!B4:B45,"John", 'CAPACITY'!D4:DD45, "Project Alpha")`

The goal should be to be able to say at the end how many hours per project per month each team member has incurred.

In the sheet, each line represents 2 working hours.

The cream on the cherry would be if you could distinguish in the script between Normal Hrs and Overcapacity. Should be: 4 x 2 = 8 hrs as normal day + additional hrs = overcapacity.

Can anyone help me building the script or at least give me a hint? I don't know much about scripts. That would be amazing! If you need more information, pls let me know.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for sharing your spreadsheet. Would you please ensure that it includes an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula in the screenshot below is situated below the data range, but that's not critical, it could go on anywhere.

---

**Summary: Hours by Project by Day**

[image: Screenshot]

---

Total shifts: `=COUNTA(D4:D45)`

Per Project (Normal Time): `=countifs({D$4:D$7,D$11:D$14,D$18:D$21,D$25:D$28, D$32:D$35,D$39:D$42},$C50)`

Per Project (Overtime): `=countifs({D$8:D$10,D$15:D$17,D$22:D$24,D$29:D$31, D$36:D$38,D$43:D$45},$C50)`

Total project shifts: `=sum(D49:D65)`

Proof (s. be zero): `=D66-D47`

The criteria range in [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) is expressed as an array (each array segment relates to a specific employee). This simplifies the formula and requires only one criterion.

The formula can be copied across the data table

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, it's working! Many thanks for your support here! I probably just thought it was too complicated. In any case, I am very happy about the result and thank you very much!